# Степень вложенности комментария

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, рекурсия

Как к каждому комментарию добавить уровень вложенности
[метод который обходит коллекцию рекурсивно](http://pastebin.com/W4tjJUhn)
Я бы воспользовался готовыми библиотеками, но я хочу разобраться с этим сам.

Структура таблицы комментарьев
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может есть хранимая процедура которая будет возвращать уровень вложенности комментария

Answer (score 1):

Зачем использовать рекурсию, если велосипеды уже придуманы?
Один - запрос, и все дочерние элементы получены.
Один - запрос и все родительские элементы получены.
Все просто. Рекомендую к прочтению: https://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database/

Описанный здесь способ сможет снизить затраты ОЗУ и процессора, соответственно увеличив время работы

Answer (score 0):

выполнить вашу задачу можно с помощью [рекурсивных ОТВ](http://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/28.html) (в статье разобран подобный пример)

можно самому реализовать это с помощью хранимой процедуры, см эту [статью](http://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/22.html)